# Android Auto, desktop head unit won't start

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-auto

I develop and app with Android Auto capabilities. I have two computer, one under Windows with no problems and my other under Ubuntu 16.04 (where DHU won't start).

When I start the DHU, I got this message:

```
./desktop-head-unit: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know which package should I install to solve this problem...

Tkanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libraries, open terminal, type in the command,

sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libportaudio2 libpng12-0

see details at https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html